# How to make background element receive the click event of foreground element

Tags: html, css

I have a background and foreground div in a container div. I would like the click event on the foreground div to be sent through to the background div and let the background div manage the click event.

What is the correct Angular 2+ way to do this?

My divs look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="foreground"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.background {
}

.foreground {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really about angular, you can try using the `pointer-events` css property

```
.foreground
{
    /* other properties */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```